# using grep command to get spectfic word [LINUX]

Tags: grep, xargs

I have a test.txt file with links for example:

```
google.com?test=
google.com?hello=
```

and this code

```
xargs -0 -n1 -a FUZZvul.txt -d '\n' -P 20 -I % curl -ks1L '%/?=DarkLotus' | grep -a 'DarkLotus'
```

When I type a specific word, such as DarkLotus, in the terminal, it checks the links in the file and it brings me the word which is reflected in the links i provided in the test file
There is no problem here, the problem is that I have many links, and when the result appears in the terminal, I do not know which site reflected the DarkLotus word.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try -n option. It shows the line number of file with the matched line.

Best Regards,
Haridas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are up to there, but can you invert it? `grep` by default prints matching lines. The problem here is you are piping the input from the stdout of the previous commands into `grep`, and that can lack context at `grep`. Since you have a file to work with:

```
$ grep 'DarkLotus' FUZZvul.txt
```

If your intention is to also follow the link then it might be easier to write a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in `grep 'DarkLotus FUZZvul.txt`
do
  link=# extract link from line
  echo ${link}
  curl -ks1L ${link}
done
```

Then you could make your script accept user input:

```
#/bin/bash

word="${0}"

for line in `grep ${word} FUZZvul.txt`
...
```

and then

```
$ my_link_getter "DarkLotus"
https://google?somearg=DarkLotus
...
```

And then you could make the txt file a parameter.

etc.